# Powershell - Run a script located at a remote machine which inturn access files from a network share

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to execute a powershell script located at a remote machine using the below command and it works great

invoke-command (powershell c:\install\install.ps1) -computername box1 -credential (get-credential)

The above script in-turn copies files from a network share (using robocopy) - It fails complaining the location doesn't exist. Found out it was due to permission issue. It works when I explicitly mentioned in the script to use the following credentials for the share

net use \share1\files password /user:username

Is there a way to pass in the same credentials used to run the script to be used by the script to access other resources in the remote machine?

Thanks!
Sanjeev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is credSSP. Check this post:
http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1230

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I'm trying to use remoting in Windows Server 2003 and couldn't use CredSSP. Is there a work around?

Comment: Unfortunately, no workaround. One thing you can do is to use a domain controller as the second hop. Which means you initiate Invoke-Command on a 2003 system and run the script block on domain controller and then access the file share of a 3rd machine. A domain controller (windows 2008/2008 R2) always delegates credentials and  you dont need to use CredSSP

Comment: I finally found a way to do this by adding a new psdrive in the profile.ps1 script to the network share and using the drive. http://tinyurl.com/6ef4sb2

Answer (score 0):

Pass the credentials as arguments to the power shell script when invoking it remotely using `invoke-command`. Pass these credentials to the `next` script from `install.ps1`.