# Forced using the PSSessionOption -NoMachineProfile BUT SPFarm.Local is null

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2007

I am currently writing a Powershell module to provide functions for installing / operating SharePoint 2007.
One of my scripts checks the health of SharePoint servers farm.

So I use Remote Powershell : using New-PSSession.
In my Virtualized test farm (Windows server 2003, same domain, same admin...), the New-PSSession cmdlet failed :

[image]

After googling it, the only solution I saw was to use the NoMachineProfile option : 
That solved my problem.

Now the problem :
I need to use SharePoint object : SPFarm.Local (on all servers)

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local
```

This code works locally (on all servers)
But when I run it remotely (using the NoMachineProfile option), SPFarm.Local is null !

I Suppose (I cannot check it) it is because SharePoint uses some registry values that are not loaded because of the NoMachineProfile option.

So :

1 - Do you think SPFarm.Local is null because of the NoMachineProfile option ?

2 - Do you know how can I solve the first problem without using the -NoMachineProfile option ?

Thx a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is related to the PowerShell Multi-Hop (Diagram below of what a multi-hop operation is) issue [Which was discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596053/powershell-run-a-script-located-at-a-remote-machine-which-inturn-access-files-f)... PowerShell is not able to perform a multi-hop operation by default, because your credential are not being passed to the next server... Since you are trying to contact different SP servers in the farm from a remote host. I would recommend reading the following blog entry related to multi-hop scenarios and following his instructions to correct your issue.

[Using CredSSP for multi-hop authentication](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1230)

http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1230

I know this diagram mentions file server but it’s the same basic principle.

[image: PowerShell Multi-Hop Diagram]

Comment: Thx for your quick answer.
But when I try "Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer XXX", I got this error : 
Enable-WSManCredSSP : This Powershell cmdlet is not available on the following platforms: Windows XP and Windows Server 2003.
So, no solution ?

Comment: Ah sorry my bad i missed the XP, Win2003 and earlier comment in the question... CredSSP is not avilable for those versions of the OS as per [Microsofts Multi-Hop Support in WinRM post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309365(VS.85).aspx)... I am sorry to say I think your are out of luck in that regrad. If the SP Assemblies allow for explicit username and password injection you might want to try that as an option.

Comment: On a side note... profiles are not loaded in remoting sessions. Even if you have default machine profiles on the remote serves. What I have done is implemented my own personalized new-pssession style function where i create a new session then run a invoke command that loads a series of functions on to the remote server acting like loading a user profile, this functions are defined in the codeblock section of the invoke command I then open up the session and have the bulk of my command available for use.

Comment: Well well... Confirmation : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2010/03/07/sharepoint-2010-with-windows-powershell-remoting-step-by-step.aspx  :(

Comment: Bizzarement ça marche sur un autre serveur SP (pas la même ferme, pas le même domaine...)

Comment: Ouch, I wrote last comment in french, sorry ;). So I said that it was strange because it was working on another SharePoint server (other farm, other domain...)

Comment: Well you can get around the CredSSP issue by using your Credentials explicitly when loading the SP assembly if that is an option.